# Removing blooms from these unidentified Bromeliads?

Tags: identification, indoors, pruning, flowering, bromeliads

So, I have two Bromeliads (I don't know specific names) for conversation sake, until identified I've labeled the pics Small Brom(1st 3 pics) and Larger Brom(last 2 pics) below. Please see blooms. Both of their blooms are starting to brown. I held up white paper behind each in the close ups, so it's a little easier to see color contrast.

Can you please help identify types of Bromeliads I have?

Also, at what point do I snip the blooms? And how far down do I snip? Or do I wait for them to fall off? The small Brom has 4 pups and the larger has 6, which I was told is very unusual. Is this unusual or normal? The small Brom has a bloom thats formed at the top of the leaves (doesn't have it's own stock coming from core, like the larger Brom) so I assumed where to snip the blooms would differ? I'm really unsure though.

They both have more than quadrupled in size and are not in their original pots. I didn't know until a recent post I asked about a different Brom, that I should've have reported them, and that they prefer to get root bound... So if you were curious about their pot size, that's why... My bad :(

[image: Small Brom Full View pic1]

[image: Small Brom side view of bloom pic2]

[image: Small Brom too view of bloom pic3]

[image: Larger Brom Side view of Bloom Pic1]

[image: Larger Brom Close up view of Bloom Pic2]

[image: Larger Brom sideview better light Pic3]

[image: Larger Brom Better Light Pic4]

[image: Small Brom Better light Pic4]

Comment: The second one looks like a Tillandsia of some sort, maybe T. cyanea, although the leaves seem a little too broad.  Better lit photos might help - the actual plant is not well lit in the images, particularly the first three.

Comment: I'll try to add more when I get home from work. Thanks @Bamboo

Comment: I added pics with better lighting; last 3 pics edited in @Bamboo

Comment: Just an aside, I am bad about this...your clay pot shows salt residue.  Are you using tap water?  It is starting to show in the leaves as well.  Browning tips and margins.  The plant in the clay pot has a dead center.  That needs to be removed.  How are you watering your plants?  I would try to find a friend that has a well and fill up big water bottles.  The fluoride and chlorine and heavy metals and and and that they dump in our municipal waters is not only bad for us humans but horrid for potted plants.

Comment: And definitely cut those flowers off as low as you are able.  All that seed making energy will be sent back to the plant for other more important processes.

Comment: I do use tap; Is this Naughty of me @Stormy?  and I put my broms and ferns out when rain is coming since I know plants like rain better (nitrates= green)....and (not sure if you can see it well) but there's a break partially through the bottom left leaf on the last pic, that's from my bird who decided to nibble on it. I have since moved the location of my birds play stand, away from my indoor plants. Instead of using bottled, can I used the same dechlorinator I use for my fish tanks to dechlorinate tap water? Dechlorinating my water was mentioned to me on Stack a day or so ago....

Comment: But I'm not sure of an inexpensive way to do so, without having a rain barrel. Rain barrel is not an option for me at this location I'm currently living

Comment: Even rain water is incredibly suspect for heavy metals.  Chlorine is not the big problem.  Cl sublimates into gas for easily.  Cl is responsible for the better health of 3rd world nations.  Nitrates in rain water? You need a filter to get rid of the fluorides and heavy metals in your tap water...for YOUR own health.  Let me know if you find one, haven't searched for awhile.  The dechlorinators I've no experience at all.

Comment: btw...Christy B.  Harvesting rain water in my state is ILLEGAL.  Can you believe this?

Answer (score 3):

The first plant is a [Guzmania](http://www.bromeliads.info/guzmania-bromeliad/) possibly lingulata.

The second plant is likely to be a [Vriesea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vriesea) or possibly a variety of Guzmania.

They are both tough plants and you should not overthink maintenance on these plants.  Remove the flower at the base when it doesn't look good.  I have seen florists get some silver or sparkly spray paint and go to town on the flower with no ill effects on the plant.

Comment: What's the orange ball shaped thing in the foliage of the second picture?

Comment: It's a decorative snail pin @Bamboo. He's about an inch wide if that helps in size comparison

Comment: @ChristyB. - ha ha, I've been puzzling over that, couldn't even see it properly in the earlier pics. I agree with Kevinsky's ID...specially now I know the orange thing isn't part of the plant!